# Invoking VS Code 1.82 from WSL2 (Ubuntu) using `code .` does not return me the prompt. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After updating Visual Studio Code, when I launch it from Ubuntu terminal on WSL2 using code . command the VS Code window is opened with content of the current directory but the terminal doesn't return to `$` prompt unless I press <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>.

The `code` command should open VS Code window and return me back to `$` prompt so that I can enter other commands. That's how the command used to behave before updating VS Code to version 1.82.3.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/287355

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known recent (at the time of this writing) issue: [Launching VSCode from WSL2 terminal doesn't return command prompt
#8985](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8985). The cause is not yet known. Some users report that they no longer have the issue in version 1.83 of VS Code.

Current workarounds that people are using for affected versions include:

- Interrupting the process running in the shell by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in the terminal where they run `code` ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8985#issuecomment-1722316463))
- Running that command as a background job by appending `&` to the command in which they run `code` ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8985#issuecomment-1722590235))
- One user stopped getting the issue after upgrading their WSL from 1.2.5.0 to a pre-release version, 2.0.3.0 ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8985#issuecomment-1742213789))

Considering the timing of this question and the GitHub issue (Sept 14th), I don't think this is solely a problem related to WSL 1.2.5.0, since [that was released](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/1.2.5) back on April 19th.

I'll keep this answer updated as more info comes.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues code commandline return prompt`".